# Emacs: cmdproxy.exe has encountered an issue and needs to close

Tags: windows, emacs, elisp

I opened up emacs today and I got an error when I started typing into the `#include`:

[image]

This only happens when I start typing. At first I thought it had something to do with my `~/.emacs` file so I opened it up and commented certain things. Eventually I found that when I comment the following line the problem goes away:

```
(ac-config-default)
```

I'm using `yasnippet` and `auto-complete` packages in my lisp file for my editor. The problem seems to be the above line when using `auto-complete` This is the full script of my `~/.emacs` up to that point:

```
(require 'cc-mode)

(load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
;; Replace "sbcl" with the path to your implementation
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")

(setq-default c-basic-offset 4 c-default-style "linux")
(setq-default tab-width 4 indent-tabs-mode t)
(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)

; start package.el with emacs
(require 'package)
; add MELPA to repository list
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
; initialize package.el
(package-initialize)

; start auto-complete with emacs
(require 'auto-complete)
; do default config for auto config
(require 'auto-complete-config)

; THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM:
(ac-config-default)
```

Is there something wrong I've done here? Something I may have forgotten to do?

Comment: please include your version of emacs and the data from the error report, it is almost certainly failing while trying to call gtags. First try running emacs as admin and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @JordonBiondo This is GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600)
 of 2013-03-17 on MARVIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try running emacs as admin and see if the problem goes away, I've had trouble with permissions issues in windows before similar to this.

The error is almost certainly caused by the gtags autocomplete source for C.

If you are not using gtags, you can likely fix the problem by removing the source from autocomplete.

```lisp
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 
          (lambda () (remove-from-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-gtags)) t t)
```

Not a perfect solution, but a possible one.

Comment: Where do I insert this?

Comment: And how do I run as administrator?

Comment: right click on the emacs icon, if that's how you're running it and run as admin, if you're running from the command prompt or another shell, make sure you start that up as admin and then run emacs. Also you can append that line to the end of your init. But try admin first.

Comment: It's asking for a password but I don't think I've ever set up a password. When I press okay without a password it fails and when I tried other possibe passwords it still didn't work. I only use my user, never used admin. Is there something I can do?